# Unable to install codecs

Tags: codecs

I keep receiving this message 
"unable to install gstreamer multimedia codecs as download failed: w:not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend"
When trying to install media codecs

Comment: are you using **sudo** command? this error is because you don't have write permissions in **/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend** folder

Comment: Please click [edit] to let us know these facts. 1) Which OS is installed (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.)? 2) Which release number?  Please do not use Add Comment; Comments are a channel from us to you, whereas the Question should contain all the facts you have about the issue.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? Did you try installing VLC or the remaining codecs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to watch videos, I highly recommend installing VLC player.
`sudo apt install vlc`. It has all the codecs needed to play back any video that I have ever opened in it. Be sure to set VLC as the default video player so it opens automatically. I had the same issues that you had and tried numerous times to install the various codecs, but it is much easier to just install VLC.